# Can I get UK residence card, if I have Permanent Residence from Czech Republic?

Tags: united-kingdom

I've got permanent residence from Czech Republic. On the card it's written EU permanent residence which I guess valid to EU countries. Can I get UK residence card if I decide to move to UK?

Comment: What's your citizenship/status in the Czech Republic? There are some subtle rules but in general a residence permit from one EU country is **not** valid in other EU countries and cannot be easily exchanged (even if it is in the “common format”, with EU logo and all). So you would need to establish residence rights from scratch in the UK (which could be reasonably easy if you are an EU citizen or the spouse of an EU citizen).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot!

It is EU Resident Permit, but it has been issued by the Czech Republic. It is guaranteed that you can live and work in Czech Republic indefinitely, but other member states may restrict new residents.

In general, you need to apply for the UK residency. However, note if you get the UK Permanent Residence, you will lose your Czech Permanent Residence. You can have EU Permanent Residence from one country.